Epigraph translation, according to Chicago Manual of Style
There is a book by John Doe in which there is an epigraph by Goethe, which is translated into English by Jim Oe.
Chapter 1

                  Rosen sind rot,
                  Veilchen sind blau.[1]
                  - Goethe

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecte-
tur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
magna aliqua ...

-----
[1] "Roses are red, Violets are blue." - transl. by Jim Oe

What is the correct way to "style" the translation according to The Chicago Manual of Style?

E.g., should there will be a dash or instead a comma before the word "transl."?
Should the translation be enclosed in quotation marks, or should it be typed using italic font and without quotation marks instead? Or maybe it should be used parentheses? "Roses are red, Violets are blue." (transl. by Jim Oe)
Maybe something else


@Ben This is a fictional text. I'm not the author. The translation is a part of author's text and its attribution to Jim Oe is intentionally wrong. That is, I must mention Jim Oe as the translator. And I don't think moving the translation to the copyright page is a way to go, because there are many epigraphs in the book, not just a single one. And so the epigraph translation, I think, should be a regular footnote.

The Chicago Manual of Style says:

14.38 Quotation within a note. When a note includes a quotation, the source normally follows the terminal punctuation of the quotation. The entire source need not be put in parentheses ...

One estimate of the size of the reading public at this time was that of Sydney Smith: “Readers are fourfold in number compared with what they were before the beginning of the French war.... There are four or five hundred thousand read­ ers more than there were thirty years ago, among the lower orders.” Letters, ed. Nowell C. Smith (New York: Oxford University Press, 1953), 1:341, 343.


Your example should therefore read:


“Roses are red, Violets are blue.” Transl. by Jim Oe.



Note
The CMOS requires that you give your sources. In your example, neither the source for the original nor for the translation are given. Therefore, according to the CMOS, the footnote would be considered incorrect.
